# JMS Serializer - Cross reference issue

Tags: symfony, annotations, jmsserializerbundle

My entity has two self-referencing `OneToMany` relationships `children` and `revisions`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\CMS;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("ALL")
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Page[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CoreBundle\Entity\CMS\Page", mappedBy="parent")
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"page_children"})
     * @JMS\Expose()
     */
    protected $children;

    /**
     * @var Page[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CoreBundle\Entity\CMS\Page", mappedBy="page")
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"revisions"})
     * @JMS\Expose()
     *
     */
    protected $revisions;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", value={"main", "revision"})
     *
     * @JMS\Expose()
     *
     */
    protected $type;

    #...
}
```

I am exposing two collections - `children` and `revisions`. Additionally `type` is exposed - it's an indicator if `Page` belongs to `revisions` or not.

Request `{{host}}/api/pages?expand=page_children` returns result which includes `Pages` of both types.

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "main",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "type": "main",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "type": "main",
                    "children": []

                },
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "type": "revision",
                    "children": []

                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "id": "4,
            "type": "revision",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "id": "2',
    "type": "revision",
    "children": []
}
```

I'd like to exclude from the response `Pages` which type is `revision`. So my final result would look like:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "main",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "type": "main",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "type": "main",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Usually, to filter results I'm using [LexikFormFilterBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle). 
However in this case combined request like:

```
{{host}}/api/expand=page_children&page_filter[type]=main
```

works only for the first level results.

I thought about [Dynamic Exclusion Strategy](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#dynamic-exclusion-strategy) or [Subscribing Handler](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers#subscribing-handlers). Unfortunately, I cannot figure out the solution.

Comment: This seems like an interesting problem. Please edit and add a little bit more details. So far, I'm understanding that you may query a Page object, get it's children and revisions but only show children of revisions. Correct?

Comment: @DonOmondi I've added details, let me know if it is more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry haven't loggedin for a few hours. There is the one solution but it's a bit lengthy but gives a lot of flexibility, I've used it when dealing with complex APIs. If you like it, I can post as an answer with more detail. Basically, create a separate class that you will populate (on __construct) from the serialized array during which you omit the type you don't want.

Comment: @DonOmondi You mean using DTO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I solved this problem implementing [Subscribing Handler](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers#subscribing-handlers)

```
<?php

namespace CoreBundle\Serializer\Subscriber\CMS;

use App\Entity\CMS\Page;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\Events;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\PreSerializeEvent;
use JMS\Serializer\Handler\SubscribingHandlerInterface;

class PageSubscriber extends SubscribingHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            [
                'event' => Events::PRE_SERIALIZE,
                'method' => 'onPreSerialize',
                'class' => Page::class,
                'format' => 'json',
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param PreSerializeEvent $event
     */
    public function onPreSerialize(PreSerializeEvent $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getObject();

        if (!$entity instanceof Page) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->isSerialisingForGroup($event, 'exclude_revisions')) {
            $this->excludeRevisions($entity);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Page $page
     */
    private function excludeRevisions(Page $page): void
    {
        foreach ($page->getChildren() as $child) {
            if ($child->getStatus() === 'revision') {
                $page->removeChild($child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Disadvantage**: All data is fetched at this point. Elements `"type": "revision"` will be included in non-first level and it will expand which can lead to `Allowed memory size exhausted`.

#### Another possible approach would be to use Doctrine `postLoad` Event.

```
<?php

namespace App\Service\Doctrine;

use App\Entity\CMS\Page;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use RuntimeException;

class PageListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    /** @var bool $canFlush */
    private $canFlush = true;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Events::postLoad,
            Events::onFlush,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param Page $page
     */
    public function onPostLoad(Page $page): void
    {
        $children = $page->getChildren();

        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if ($child->getStatus === 'revision') {
                $page->removeChild($child);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs
     */
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityDeletions() as $entityDeletion) {
            if ($entityDeletion instanceof Page){
                throw new RuntimeException('Flushing Page at this point will remove all Revisions.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Disadvantage**: Can be dangerous and narrow possible future changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it through a custom method inside your class and telling JMS to use it.

`/**
      * @VirtualProperty
      * @SerializedName("my_collection")
      */
     public function getMyCollection()
     {
         return $this->collection->filterByType.....
     }`

If you want to make it dynamic you can store some data inside of a virtual property and use it in this method.
To control the depth use `@JMS\MaxDepth(depth=1)`.

But conceptually, it seems like a very bad idea. I would rather review the scope and maybe split things in proper way.

Comment: I could try this solution. Could you improve a bit your answer? Do you mean using `Criteria(Criteria::expr()->...`?

Comment: Yes. But the point is not in how you do filtering, as long as you have it correctly filtered. Main point was to expose it through custom getters which will prepare the data and not through existing properties.

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski but still I would suggest you to review your data model instead of doing dirty hacks.

Comment: I agree neither solution isn’t good. But unfortunately model can’t be changed at the moment. That’s why I needed help.